# Data binding WPF populating combobox from mysql database Vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

Hi am converting my old winform app to WPF. Just getting started with it.
How do bind data from mysql table to a combobox. Below is my winform code which works.

```
Try
        mysqlcnx.Open()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from mydb.eventlist", mysqlcnx)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(table)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "EventName"
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I tried converting it like this but doesnt work.

```
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from mydb.eventlist", conn)
            Dim table As New System.Data.DataTable()
            da.Fill(table)
            'EventcomboCon.ItemsSource = New BindingGroup(table, Nothing)
            EventcomboCon.DisplayMemberPath = "EventName"
            EventcomboCon.SelectedIndex = -1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: If you intend to use it like you did WinForms then there's limited point moving to WPF in the first place. If you want to get the most out of it then you ought to be using the MVVM design pattern, which would mean redesigning your app from the ground up, rather than just trying to write equivalent code. What you do is up to you but, if you're not using MVVM, you're not really using WPF.

Comment: Do you have examples of mvvm in vb.net, not used c# that much

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. There's loads of information out there about MVVM. If most of the examples are in C# then you'll need to learn to read C# at least. It's not that hard for the most part. All the types and members are the same and the code structure is the same. There's just generally small differences in syntax. If you can understand the principles demonstrated then it's easy to implement them in VB. You also might download and install Instant VB from tangible Software Solutions for converting snippets. It's better than any online code converter.

Answer (score 0):

By searching the web, I was able to determine that the code should be like this:

```vb
With myComboBox
    .DisplayMemberPath = "EventName"
    .ItemsSource = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
End With
```

You should have been able to find that same information.